# an adjective for someone who is good at framing things

Tags: word-request

Is there an adjective in English for a person who is very skillful in presenting a situation in words in such way that it is almost not what the real situation is, yet not lying?

For example, "There was a racing competition yesterday. I almost came first and Jack came almost the last!" (only two people participated in that competition).

Comment: 'skilled spin doctor'.

Comment: @thelawnet - Is this a common term?

Comment: spin doctor is a noun, and is a common term. there is however no adjective specifically, only a noun or verb

Comment: @thelawnet - I see. Can I use it like this: "Jack is quite a spin doctor" or "Jack is very much a spin doctor"?

Comment: yes, although I would probably say 'Jack is quite the spin doctor', you could also try 'Jack can spin any situation', etc.

Comment: @thelawnet - I see. Thank you.